# Original column name from T-SQL query that yields columns AFTER the original column name was reclassified

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a relatively standard sql query with several table joins and where clauses that all relate a loan after it has been reclassified to ORE (Other Real Estate Owned). I am trying to list the value of one of the ORIGINAL fields (category) that has been changed now that it is ORE.

Say the original category was 1 for 'Consumer' but once the loan goes to ORE, the category is a 12 which includes ALL original categories (1,2,3,4)

Therein lies the problem - I need to show the ORE loans for only say categories 1 & 2.  Nothing I've tried works - I'm assuming because the where clause at the bottom of the query specifies that I need various fields that all tie to the ORE status but NOT to the original categories. I've tried subqueries (don;t work because they are 'above' the main query's where clause...

Any general guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the query and the subquery below it:

```
SELECT
A.ACCTNO
E.SNAME,
B.OREO_ID,
A.OREODATE,
GC.CATEGORY
FROM
DBO.LOAN_SYSTEM AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.ORE AS B
ON A.OREO_ID = B.OREO_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.LOAN_TITLE AS C
ON A.OREO_ID = C.OREO_ID AND C.SEQ = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM DBO.LOAN_FC WHERE ISDELETED = 0 AND ISDISMISSED IS NULL) AS D
ON A.OREO_ID = D.OREO_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.TBL_GROUP_CODES GC
ON E.[GROUP] = GC.GROUP_CODE
WHERE
D.FC_ID IS NOT NULL AND C.FORECLOSUREDATE IS NOT NULL AND GC.CATEGORY IN (1,2) --DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE ONCE IN OREO = 12
AND
E.STATUS NOT IN (2,8)

--SUBQUERY GETS ORIGINAL CATEGORY
SELECT
B.ACCTNO, C.CATEGORY
FROM DBO.LOAN_SYSTEM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.LOAN_DAILY_INFO B
ON B.ACCTNO = A.ACCTNO
AND B.TYPE = A.TYPE
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.TBL_GROUP_CODES C
ON C.GROUP_CODE = B.[GROUP]
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.TBL_LOAN_TYPES D
ON D.TYPE = A.TYPE
WHERE B.STATUS NOT IN (2,8)
AND C.CATEGORY IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Include the query you tried in your question.

Comment: Also include sample data

Comment: The key is the 3rd last line of the top query - it doesn't work because once the loan foes to OREO, it has a category of 12.  This top query is needed because as you would guess, it reports critical data aboutloans in OREO - just not the original category - which the second query does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here.. but you might need to use EXISTS here.

```
SELECT  A.ACCTNO,
        E.SNAME,
        B.OREO_ID,
        A.OREODATE,
        GC.CATEGORY
FROM    DBO.LOAN_SYSTEM AS A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.ORE AS B ON A.OREO_ID = B.OREO_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.LOAN_TITLE AS C ON A.OREO_ID = C.OREO_ID
                                               AND C.SEQ = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM DBO.LOAN_FC WHERE ISDELETED = 0 AND ISDISMISSED IS NULL
                        ) AS D ON A.OREO_ID = D.OREO_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.TBL_GROUP_CODES GC ON D.[GROUP] = GC.GROUP_CODE
WHERE   D.FC_ID IS NOT NULL
        AND C.FORECLOSUREDATE IS NOT NULL
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    DBO.LOAN_DAILY_INFO F
                    JOIN DBO.TBL_GROUP_CODES G ON G.GROUP_CODE = F.[GROUP]
            WHERE   F.STATUS NOT IN (2,8)
                    AND G.CATEGORY IN (1,2)
                    AND F.ACCTNO = A.ACCTNO
                    AND F.TYPE = A.TYPE 
        ) 
        AND D.STATUS NOT IN (2,8)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jamie - let me try this out, and sorry if I didn't make it more clear.  My top query works fine, but as I noted, once the loan goes into OREO or a Category 12, the old category (in this case 1 or 2 is updated), but I need to see that original category.  Thanks again and more soon.